# Is it possible to enable content types and use a document template?

Tags: content-type, document-template, sharepoint-library

I have a library that uses a document template, and this is essential to the process that uses the library. I want to enable content types so I can remove a certain field from the edit item and view item forms. However, when I enable content types, this disables the templates option.

Is there a way around this/a way to use both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enable content types, and make the default content type to be your document template.

Comment: Do you have a good reference or guide I can use to show me how to do it?

Comment: As described in this article, you need to create a content type of type: Document, upload the document to this content type, then add this content type to your library. 

http://www.sharepointchick.com/archive/2011/01/07/using-content-types-with-document-templates-when-using-quotnew-documentrdquo.aspx